# NodeJS-ExpressJS going extremely slow when accesing from outside the LAN

Tags: node.js, express

I have a NodeJS server deployed with ExpressJS and the thing is that when I access it from computers in the same LAN works very well, but when I try to reach the server from outside, I have to wait almost 20 seconds to get all the data.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah... your outside connection isn't as fast as you would like it to be.  This has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: But the thing is that with another server in Java,  it works properly...

Comment: I doubt that you have actually narrowed down this problem do your application.  You would have to write something specifically to do this.  Have you properly ruled out "intelligent" network devices for bandwidth throttling, proxy servers, intermittent problems, network errors, etc.?  Even if you had, we don't just magically know what your code looks like.  This question is unanswerable.